# How good it is from design perspective to have active component in background within an API

Tags: java, api-design

I have a distributed software system which is in pure java SE environment. It has an API which clients uses for accessing the services. Client may be web applications or desktop applications.

API communicates to the software over socket, using object streams.

I want to build a server push kind of system for near real time notifications to clients.

Now for that i need some active component with in API which receives those notifications and acts on them. Client should be able to register their actions via API like

```
service.login();
service.addNotificationHandler(handler);
```

My question is How good it is from design perspective to have active components (threads) in background within an API.

If it is a bad choice, what is the right one for this scenario ?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with background threads running in an implementation of an API, lots of components do this (e.g. in some way you can view Tomcat as a servlet-api implementation using lots of threads). Do consider the environment the component is running in: some environments like Java EE generally do not like threads started outside the server (JBoss, Glassfish) and require the thread to be somehow provided by the server.

In any case make sure that these background threads stop running once the client signals it is done using the service/component (e.g. via `service.logout()`). 

Many components forget to do this which is very annoying when the implementation is used. E.g. log4j had a `watchdog` thread that was never stopped and recently the MySQL driver added an "abandoned connection thread" which [fails to stop](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69526). For occasional use these issues are not important, but in server environments (where stuff has to, preferably, run forever) these issues are serious enough to consider an alternative implementation (which might be less functional complete but does not require a hack to fix).

Comment: What are the alternatives for java EE environment then ?

Comment: won't there be a performance issue when there is a service instance created for every login session and there are many active sessions at a given instance of time ??

Comment: @AmitP For Java EE: dig deep in the Java EE documentation of the container/server - there should be an option to create/get a reference to a container-managed threadpool that you can use (it is cumbersome but I figured it out and got it working for JBoss 5.1 at one point).

Comment: @AmitP About performance issue: that is where the challenge is (e.g. how to detect a client that crashed and did not properly close/disconnect). But if you can find a framework/technology that does this kind of heavy lifting for you, try to use it. E.g. Tomcat 8 supports the kind of scenario you describe with the WebSockets implementation or just via using (servlet) sessions.